# Unable to send a PUT request on PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am learning Django and trying to create a Game REST API using Django REST framework.I am not sure how to update the publisher field.Do I need to create another Serializer for my Publisher class and implement a save method?

I am using POSTMAN to send a PUT request and I am recieving this:

```
"publisher": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received unicode."
  ]
```

when I send a JSON request

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "release_date": "1979-01-01",
  "rating": 5,
  "comment": "Terrible Game!",
  "publisher": "Me"
```

}

models.py

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(
        null=True, blank=True,
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from game.models import Game, Publisher

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    publisher = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=Publisher.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('pk','name', 'release_date', 'rating', 'comment', 'publisher')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new 'Game' instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Game.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing 'Game' instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.release_date = validated_data.get('release_date',instance.release_date)
        instance.rating = validated_data.get('rating', instance.rating)
        instance.comment = validated_data.get('comment', instance.comment)
        instance.publisher = validated_data.get('publisher', instance.publisher)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class GameDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a game instance.
    """
    def get_object(self,pk):
        try:
            return Game.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Game.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        game = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = GameSerializer(game)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        game = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = GameSerializer(game, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        game = self.get_object(pk)
        game.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending a string ("Me") as the publisher attribute. That's why you get your `"Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received unicode."` error.

Since `publisher` is a `ForeignKey` in your `Game` model, you'll have to get the instance of "Me" `Publisher` before saving it in your database.

One possible approach is to modify your `update()` method in your serializer and search for the right instance :

```
instance.publisher = Publisher.objects.get_or_create(name=validated_data.get('publisher'))
```

and then call `instance.save()`.